# How to regenerate SQL scripts by Play Slick Evolution

Tags: playframework, slick, playframework-2.4, slick-3.0

I am using Play 2.4.0 and Slick 3.1. I am trying to figure out how I can regenerate SQL by Slick evolution. I modified my classes in models.* but no sql scripts are regenerated. Please help.

Here is my configuration:

plugin.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.4.0")
```

build.sbt

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
・・・
evolutions,
"com.typesafe.play" % "play-slick_2.11" % "1.1.1",
"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick-evolutions" % "1.1.1",
・・・　
)
```

As mentioned in the official document https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Evolutions or the question " [Regenerate evolution scripts in play 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806926/regenerate-evolution-scripts-in-play-2) ", I am running my app like below.

- I am running myapp in the dev mode
- in application.conf I have this line not commented :

  - slick.default="models.*"
  - play.evolutions.enabled=true
- there is only one file in your evolutions folder and it's 1.sql
- it has this comment at the beginning:

  # To stop Slick DDL generation, remove this comment and start using Evolutions

Comment: Probably you can't here more info: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/PlaySlickMigrationGuide#DDL-support-was-removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible since 2.4, I made some workaround:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35383919/2235939

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi, Thanks. How can I run this?

Comment: It will run automatically during app start

Comment: I tried ./activator run and ./activator start but it was not executed.

Comment: I've updated answer, you need also add in config enabled module